# Java Waffle Authentication - FilterSecurityInterceptor - Failed to authorize filter invocation with attributes [authenticated]

Tags: java, rest, spring-security, waffle

I have a Java Spring rest api with Waffle authentication.

Here is my code.

```
@Configuration
public class WaffleConfig {

    
    @Bean
    public WindowsAuthProviderImpl waffleWindowsAuthProvider() {
        return new WindowsAuthProviderImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider negotiateSecurityFilterProvider(
            WindowsAuthProviderImpl windowsAuthProvider) {
        return new NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider(windowsAuthProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public BasicSecurityFilterProvider basicSecurityFilterProvider(
            WindowsAuthProviderImpl windowsAuthProvider) {
        return new BasicSecurityFilterProvider(windowsAuthProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterProviderCollection waffleSecurityFilterProviderCollection(
            NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider negotiateSecurityFilterProvider,
            BasicSecurityFilterProvider basicSecurityFilterProvider) {
        SecurityFilterProvider[] securityFilterProviders =
                {negotiateSecurityFilterProvider, basicSecurityFilterProvider};
        return new SecurityFilterProviderCollection(securityFilterProviders);
    }

    @Bean
    public NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint(
            SecurityFilterProviderCollection securityFilterProviderCollection) {
        NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint =
                new NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint();
        negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint.setProvider(securityFilterProviderCollection);
        return negotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public NegotiateSecurityFilter waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter(
            SecurityFilterProviderCollection securityFilterProviderCollection) {
        NegotiateSecurityFilter negotiateSecurityFilter = new NegotiateSecurityFilter();
        negotiateSecurityFilter.setProvider(securityFilterProviderCollection);
        return negotiateSecurityFilter;
    }

    // This is required for Spring Boot so it does not register the same filter twice
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean waffleNegotiateSecurityFilterRegistration(
            NegotiateSecurityFilter waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setFilter(waffleNegotiateSecurityFilter);
        registrationBean.setEnabled(false);
        return registrationBean;
    }


}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private NegotiateSecurityFilter negotiateSecurityFilter;

    @Autowired
    private NegotiateSecurityFilterEntryPoint entryPoint; 
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(negotiateSecurityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)                
            .headers()
            .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"))
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS); // Disable session creation;  
        
        http.cors();   
    }
    
    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {      
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication();
    }
    
}
```

```
    @GetMapping(value="/abc", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<<abc>> getAbc(){
                
        ....
        
    }
```

When calling getAbc controller method from the angular frontend, it doesn't even gets to the breakpoint in the first line of the method.

Before that I get the following error:

```
[DEBUG] 2023-10-25 16:05:47.999 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /abc
[DEBUG] 2023-10-25 16:05:48.003 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
[DEBUG] 2023-10-25 16:05:48.027 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[DEBUG] 2023-10-25 16:05:48.038 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] FilterSecurityInterceptor - Failed to authorize filter invocation [GET /abc] with attributes [authenticated]
[DEBUG] 2023-10-25 16:05:48.039 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint - Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
[DEBUG] 2023-10-25 16:05:48.041 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
[DEBUG] 2023-10-25 16:05:48.045 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] FilterChainProxy - Securing GET /error
[DEBUG] 2023-10-25 16:05:48.045 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
[DEBUG] 2023-10-25 16:05:48.045 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
[DEBUG] 2023-10-25 16:05:48.046 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] FilterChainProxy - Secured GET /error
[DEBUG] 2023-10-25 16:05:48.056 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator - filter invocation [/error] denied for AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
```

If I change the configure method to add .httpBasic authorization like in the code below, it enters the controller method and successfully authenticates the user.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
        
          http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(negotiateSecurityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)                
                .headers()
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true"));  
                
          http.cors();   
                
    }
```

But then I incur in a different issue that I reported here:

[How to remove Firefox basic authentication window in a Java, Angular, Waffle application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77355122/how-to-remove-firefox-basic-authentication-window-in-a-java-angular-waffle-app)

So that is the reason I would like to make it work without basic authentication now. Like in the first version of the configure method I mentioned above.